# "Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager" in Eclipse not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, ubuntu-12.04, android-virtual-device

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and i am trying to install the required bits for development. I have the SDK downloaded and unzipped to my home directory, I have Eclipse installed. The I set the SDK path set in preferences, installed the ADT plugin.

For some reason the menu option doesn't show up.

It wont let me post images. So [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43961/window-android-sdk-and-avd-manager-in-eclipse-not-showing?noredirect=1#comment59348_43961)'s a link to the android enthusiasts page (where they told me to post here) that has the screenshots

Comment: Check if your eclipse has android development plugin

Comment: are you able to bring it up via running the "android" command via console?